# Add condition on all query maked on object

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I would like to add an "hidden" query on all my query. I explain:

Exemple with an table Car:

```
## id # color # constructor # model # destroyed
   1     blue    bmw         model1     false
   2    green  citroen       modelab    false
   3     red    nissan       modelz     false
   4     blue    bmw         modelw     true
   5    black  peugeot       modely     false
```

I would like when i make an requet like `SELECT * FROM Car WHERE colour = 'blue'`
What the real query will be: `SELECT * FROM Car WHERE colour = 'blue' AND destroyed = false`

On all my query destroyed cars will be exclude. Execpt if i write `WHERE is destroyed = true` in my query.

I've see it in symfony 1.4.x last year but i don't know how do it in symfony 2.x

Comment: Look at this tutorial http://sf.khepin.com/2011/12/data-separation-into-realms/. There they create a TreeWalker to add the condition to the query, but still need to call a bit of core before each query.

Comment: thank's. Nothing more 'transparent' ? in symfony 1.4.x it was 100% transparent if i remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think this soft delete filter is a great example for what you're trying to achieve - https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md